# Keyboard navigation for Chrome history on MacOS?

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

Once I open the Chrome history tab, and enter a search term, how may I tab through the results, and open one, with the keyboard? Tab itself is terrible on this. Things like Vimium are not allowed to operate on the Chrome history screen.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

- Cmd+Y and search
- Tab 4 times (until the top check box to the left of your top result is highlighted)
- Down arrow (to select the result you are looking for)
- Tab (once more to select result)
- Enter (to open selected result)